# How can i run a shell script on button click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

**This is my app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.post('/view', function(req, res) {
    console.log('button clicked !!');
});
app.listen(80);
```

**This is clientside.js**
This is the file where I have written ajax call to run the shell script

```
$('#runScript').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: "script",
        url: 'file:///D:/UIForCloning/TabitClient.sh',
        success: function(data) {
            console.log("Success");
        },
        error: function(error) {
            console.log("error");
        }
    });
});
```

**This is view.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
    <button id='runScript'>LED on</button>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src='clientside.js'></script>
</body>
```

Comment: i dont think that javascript/browser can access the file system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're trying to achieve is different from what you have coded.
**How?**

1. The `url` in ajax call points to the url which you wish to access, in your case, posting data. But, your `url` points to a script here, which I guess makes no meaning.
2. As far as I can make out from your code, you aren't posting anything to the `/view` in your `app.js`
3. You can run a shell script in nodejs in the same manner you run it in your terminal. You can use [child process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) which is built-in module of `nodejs`. You can use `spawn` or `exec` to run a shell script in nodejs. There are a lot of tutorials you can find on internet which explains not illustrating it here.

Here are some fine tutorials to start with `child processes`:

1. http://www.javatpoint.com/nodejs-child-process
2. https://dzone.com/articles/understanding-execfile-spawn-exec-and-fork-in-node
3. http://krasimirtsonev.com/blog/article/Nodejs-managing-child-processes-starting-stopping-exec-spawn

**PS:** you don't need to post anything through click if you're wanting to run the script. A simple approach would be:

1. Call the event handler function linked to the click event of the button (which you've implemented correctly).
2. Inside the function make a `get` request to `/view`.
3. Run the script using `exec` or `spawn` child process inside `/view`.
4. When the process finishes execution, return the results to the call you made in jquery-ajax code (to the `success:` method).

**Note:** you might get stuck in running asynchronous execution of `spawn` or `exec`, since the response will be sent before the execution finishes. In such cases, try going for synchronous calls like `spawnSync`, or use external libraries for handling asynchronous flow( example - [async](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html))

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

You will be able to execute shell scripts only from your server backend(through node.js) & for calling executables/ shell scripts, you need the module [child_process.exec()](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback) provided by node.
You can use it like so :

```
var cp = require("child_process");
cp('path_to_your_shell_script', function(error, stdout, stderr){//This is where the shell script is executed and the error or i/o results are passed in as arguments to the callback

})
```